# Load data from R into PosgreSQL database without losing constraints

Tags: r, database, postgresql, dataframe

I'm trying to import some dataframe from R into my PostgreSQL database. The tables are defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE fact_citedpubs(
citedpubs_id serial CONSTRAINT fact_citedpubs_pk PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
originID integer REFERENCES dim_country(country_id),
yearID integer REFERENCES dim_year(year_id),
citecount double precision
);
```

In my dataframe I have values for originID, yearID and citecount. My dataframe looks like this

```
|  YEAR | GEO_DESC |OBS_VALUE
|    8  |      1   | 13.29400
|    17 |      2   | 4.42005
|    17 |      1   | 12.95001
|    15 |      1   | 11.61365
|    14 |      1   | 13.48174
```

To import this dataframe in the postgresql database I use the function `dbWriteTable(con, 'fact_citedpubs', citations, overwrite = TRUE)`
Because of using `overwrite = TRUE` Postgresql drops all the earlier set contstraints (primary-, foreign keys and datatypes). Is there any other way to import data into a postgresql database from R while keeping the constraints that were set in advance?

Many thanks!

Comment: AFAIK [overwrite=TRUE](http://web.mit.edu/~r/current/lib/R/library/DBI/html/dbWriteTable.html) essentially recreates the table if it exists. If you want to drop all rows but keep the table then try `overwrite=FALSE, append=FALSE`. If you want to keep existing rows, then `append=TRUE`? Alternately, you may need to ETL into a temporary table (probably `temporary`), and then transfer rows across.